# Browsersync on my port 10080

Tags: wordpress, gruntjs, xampp, browser-sync

I can't get Grunt's browser sync to update my changes. I have not use Grunt much so I am a bit new to this. Maybe some of you know what could be wrong?

I am using XAMPP and runs a wordpress site at:
 http://localhost:10080/wp_demo2/

(I use port 10080 to avoid conflict with Skype)

Here is my gruntfile.js (updated)

```
var root = './htdocs/wp_demo2/wp-content/themes/isak/';
module.exports = function (grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        sass: {
            options: {
                style: 'expanded', 
                precision: 5 
            },
            all: {
                files: {
                    'css/output.css': 'scss/input.scss'
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {            
            files: 'scss/**/*.scss',
            tasks: ['sass']

        },
        browserSync: {
            dev: {  
                bsFiles:
                {
                    src: [root+'css/output.css', root + '**/*.php']
                },
                options: {                    
                    watchTask: true,
                    proxy: "localhost:10080/wp_demo2"
                }
            }
        }

    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['browserSync', 'watch']);

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`files` inside Browsersync's options is a local path, not a URL. I would set port in the `path` and move the routes to the files outside `options`.

```
// ...

browserSync: {
    dev: {
        bsFiles: {
            src: ['css/output.css', '**/*.php']
        },
        options: {
            watchTask: true,
            proxy: 'localhost:10080/wp_demo2'
        }
    }
}

// ...

grunt.registerTask('dev', ['sass', 'browserSync', 'watch']);
```

Browsersync should update when `output.css` is modified.

Your `Gruntfile.js` should be located in `.` path.

`**/*` means "search in all folders".

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did as your wrote, and it opens the site in chrome (with port 3000). Though changes in input.scss dont update the browser.

Comment: You need to run `watch` task as well. I have updated the code to include all the tasks.

Comment: Browsersync + Grunt + watch configuration is explained here: https://www.browsersync.io/docs/grunt/

Comment: Thanks. I updated my code, and read the article. But changes in input.scss still don't update the webbrowser. The grunt watch are running (i ran with grunt command), and it gives no errors. The sass part are working, since I see the updates when I refresh the webbrowser manually. Hm, I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Are you running the `dev` task that I have created? If you only run `browsersync` task `watch` does not execute. It looks like Browsersync is not locating `output.css`, try to verify the path.

Comment: The problem was the path. When I removed the root variable it worked.